# Differences between path/file-ending annotation in gitignore

Tags: git, file, path, annotations, gitignore

I am currently working on a java project. While constructing my .gitignore I noticed multiple different annotations for file endings and paths.
I linked a picture with a few examples.

What is the difference between them?

Namely I noticed the following:

- `.foo`
- `*.foo`
- `/*.foo`
- and finally `!**/src/...` (See image for this one)

[image: Different annotations examples]

Answer (score 1):

These patterns are wildmatch patterns.  In general, they are just like shell glob patterns, except that:

- `**` matches any number of files or directories or nothing at all.
- a leading `!` negates the pattern (that is, the file is not ignored).
- a leading `/` matches the root of the repository instead of the root of the file system.

See `gitignore(5)` for more details.

So `.foo` matches a file or directory anywhere in the repository called `.foo`, `*.foo` matches any file or directory anywhere in the repository that ends in `.foo`, and `/*.foo` matches a file or directory in the root of the repository that ends in `.foo`.

For the final pattern, it's relevant to look at the lines above.  First, you're ignoring any `bin` directory (but not files, since the path ends with `/`) anywhere in the tree and all of their contents.  Then, you're exempting any `bin` directory that lives underneath a `src/main` or `src/test` directory.